# Best way to cook rice to serve cold later?

Tags: flavor, rice, storage, moisture

I thought it wasn't possible to find a prepared rice that is worth being eaten cold, but I tried a prepared meal from a catering which came with tender and moist rice (even without reheating). Mine gets dry and bland.

I think it should depends on the fat added during cooking and the cooling method (covered vs uncovered, and refrigerated vs at room temperature).

I want to replicate it for preparing meals to take out.

Comment: Consider a sushi rice preparation, as one method.

Comment: Related to @Ecnerwal 's suggestion (and not an answer because I don't know why it works or if there's a better way): when I make onigiri (Japanese rice balls) I form them with hands or a mold dipped in salt water, then leave them to cool completely at room temp, and refrigerate overnight.  I let them come back to room temp before eating, and the rice is delicious.  (They can also be eaten cold, I just prefer them with the chill off.)  Likewise I portion rice I plan to reheat and allow to cool before covering and refrigerating, then heat at least partially covered.

Comment: *Fat in rice* ?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use oil as just any fat.  More to the point, you want something that is liquid at refrigerator temperature.  Butter becomes solid at that temperature and makes for a terrible texture.  Beyond that, err on the side of using an overly flavorful broth, as flavor is far more subdued at colder temperatures.  Beyond that, to ensure tenderness cook it *slightly* past al dente, as the texture will firm up as you cool it.